# skypeforlinux white screen on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype

Yesterday my `skypeforlinux` program started showing only a white screen after login. I see the chat window for a fraction of a second and then it goes white. The top menus still show (and appear functional, I can press 'quit') but no dialogs, chats, etc appear.

I have tried restarting and tried clearing the `config/skypeforlinux` directory. No change. I don't have `sudo` access to the machine so can't reinstall the software.

If I start Skype via the command line then I get the following messages just as the white screen appears:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM mic_call
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM call
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM mic_call
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM call
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM mic_call
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM call
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  42 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  10
  Current serial number in output stream:  10
```

Any ideas what's happening here? It was working fine until yesterday.

Comment: The RANDR error code suggests a problem with graphics and graphics drivers therefore reinstalling Skype if not a solution (it almost never is in a Linux based OS). But you say you're not root. If so, we can't help you, ask the administrator of that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dermaze's solution worked for me too but version 8.10.0.4 is not available any more and the URL is now broken. I was able to download the Debian package with a previous version of Skype at [this URL](https://repo.skype.com/deb/pool/main/s/skypeforlinux/).

Answer (score 7):

I am having the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04.5.

As I just posted on the [Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_signms/in-ubuntu-new-skype-version-813-cant-work-skype-it/851de0d5-51bb-4723-95cf-bbc49f801e17), a workaround for me is the usage of version 8.10.0.4. You can download it [here](https://repo.skype.com/deb/pool/main/s/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux_8.10.0.4_amd64.deb).

I deleted the ~/.config/skypeforlinux folder and installed it via terminal:
sudo dpkg -i /skypeforlinux_8.10.0.4_amd64.deb

Hopefully this works for you, too. :)

Comment: It could work (don't know, don t use it, can't test), I'm taking your word for it. But the main problem here is the OP being unable to do such things because it requires root privileges.

Comment: That is true, it's only one half of a solution - but now he can at least go to his admin with a concrete request ("please install v8.10.0.4 on my machine").

Comment: I've had the same problem with skypeforlinux 8.13.0.2.  I've reverted to version 8.11.0.4, which seems to be working (though I can't say that I like the layout changes from earlier versions).

Comment: Thank you, dermaze. I had the same problem. Your idea worked.

Answer (score 0):

Picking the latest version from here (after uninstalling Skype) helped. Awesome!
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/?type=ppas&vals=159

Answer (score -1):

worked for me, by changing to latest version of skype from 
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/?type=ppas&vals=159
1. downloaded "skypeforlinux_8.19.76.8_amd64.deb".
2. install via dpkg command